# Do you need a rabbi for exorcism?

Tags: rabbis, sheidim-demons

Do you need a rabbi for exorcism or could you do it yourself?

Like can you "kick out" a demon from yourself? Or do you need a Rabbi or someone else to help you?

If you talk  to a friend that might have a demon inside, could you give the man/woman some advice so they could fix their own problem?

Is there maybe a rabbi who have told this kinda story?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68380/exorcism-in-judaism - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/729/sheidim-are-they-fact-or-fiction?lq=1

Comment: @mbloch I don`t think this question is related,the same topic but not the same question.There is not a questions here if something is  real,here I assume that it is real and I have a questions about it.

Comment: up to day most rabbanim recommend anti-psychotic treatment.

Comment: I have heard rabbis teach on this.It can't be that uncommon

Comment: @Eagel Why can't it be uncommon?

Comment: @kouty Anti-psychotic treatment?Everyone knows that healing the mind is the worst problem,most people with these problems never get well.There are rabbis that agree on ,thats because it might be a demon.

Comment: Maybe hightly interesting to learn ethno-psychiatria and to understand the diverse approach to a same phenomen through world and cultures. Nowaday, the environmental cultural background is not proccupied with exorcism, the problem today are more linked with gender and substance abuse problems, personality disorders. It is a ennourm ectopy to speak about exorcism in occidental world.

Comment: To say it in a short way,this question is for those who agree that there are demons in this world,destroying peoples minds.

Comment: @Eagle see my comment [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68380/exorcism-in-judaism)

Answer (score 1):

If the person with the dibbuk believes it is a dibbuk then you will need someone, e.g. a rabbi, who the person believes is effective against dibbukim to remove it.

People generally assume that what was meant to happen will happen, so that the placebo effect may work with physical ailments but will probably work with spiritual and emotional ones.

Comment: I think you meant ... will probably *NOT* work with spiritual ... but wasn't sure enough to edit for you

Comment: @mbloch  Hmm.  It sounds right to me as it is.  "May" on the physical, "probably" on the spiritual/emotional.

Comment: @Mike I meant to say that it is missing a *not*, otherwise why write *but*

Comment: @mbloch I think that he means may or may not work on the physical side (but could be rare), but would most probably work on the spiritual or emotional side.